# Java Error: Could not find or load main class (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, class, classnotfoundexception

I have a java file hello.java

```
public class hello{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

I entered `javac hello.java` command to compile it and successfully generated a .class file in the same path hello.class (decomplied version)

```
 // Source code is unavailable, and was generated by the Fernflower decompiler.
public class hello {
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

However when I try to run the main function for hello class with the command `java hello`, it always turn out to throw a ClassNotFoundException

```
PS D:\Study\JAVA> java hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello
```

When I tried internal debug feature of VS Code, the main function worked normally so I can confirm that the function inside has no error.

I can also confirm the class name I applied in my command completely correct. I dont understand why this ClassNotFoundException always show up.

I know it's just a very basic question (maybe stupid). Many thanks for any possible answer.

I'm using java 1.8.0_311

I compiled the java file with `javac hello.java` and it works normally.
Then I can see a java class file - hello.class has been generated.
I tried many times to run `java hello` but always get ClassNotFoundException.
I have tried restarting the IDE or delete and rewriting the whole file but none of them works.

Comment: Where is hello.class?

Comment: In Java it is convention that class names start with an uppercase alphabet, for example `Hello.java` or `HelloWorld.java`. Naming of classes, methods and variables using is part of making your Java coding conventions - standardized, user friendly and maintainable. (This has nothing to do with the error you are seeing).

Comment: @shmosel Same path as the hello.java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing exactly that works for me (on Linux). However, I don't have java installed on Windows to test.

You can try `java -cp . hello` which will explicitly set the classpath to the current directory, which should allow `java` to find the class.

Comment: 'java -cp . hello' works for me as well, many thanks for you help!